# No render bindings in ionic

Tags: javascript, html, ionic-framework, render

I have this js:

```
$scope.updateCenter = function(center) {
  $scope.center = center
  $("#centerModal").modal("show")
};
```

And this html:

```
<form role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>{{ 'Phone' | translate}}</label>
        <input class="form-control" ng-model="center.phone">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>{{ 'Web' | translate}}</label>
        <input class="form-control" ng-model="center.web">
    </div>
</form>
```

I put `ng-model` to render data of center but it doesn't work. I put the `center` in `$scope` and I don't know why this not works.

Comment: this code is not sufficient to see problem. Please add more details.

Comment: I  put more details... it is okey?

Comment: please also share where and when updateCenter is being called.